# Homebrew installation timing out on ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

i am a beginner web developer and am learning towards block chain development as well, for that i am trying to install home brew but for some reason after trying again and again on the ubuntu terminal, the request is timing out.

what i put in the terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

and what i got in return:

```
curl:(28)  Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port  443 after 279015 ms: connection timed out.
```

any advice what i can do now?

Comment: homebrew does time out sometimes for no apparent reason. Try running the same command during non-peak hours (e.g. late at night) and maybe it won't timeout this time. Please comment if you think this should be posted as an answer.